QGIS Maptips HTML expression
I'm setting up a QGIS maptip for a layer which comprises 6 text columns.
I'm using a CASE WHEN expression in the HTML Map Tip window which is;
[% CASE WHEN "Confine" ='WNC' 
THEN 
"notesa"

ELSE "notes1"
END%]

This works and displays the attribute information correctly, but only for 2 of the 6 columns.
IS there a syntax to include notesb, notesc, notes2 etc in the statement above, or is this not possible within the maptips function in QGIS

You can concatenate multiple fields. Use the operator || if there is no null value, or the concat() function if there is any null.


Hi, thanks for your reply

That works where i only need the maptip to show on 1 line. But i need the answer to space across 4 separate lines (1 for each reply from 4 separate fields in the atribute table of the layer) I've tried adding a  and '\n' in between the "notesa" & "notesb" fields but these don't. is there a way to do this

yes, by adding a <br> between the fields :-) concat("notea", '<br>', "noteb") or "notea" || '<br>' || "noteb"
